# How to sort processes properly in System Monitor

Tags: system-monitor

System monitor's processes tab displays a bunch of processes against properties such as "% CPU", "ID", etc. However, it has some kind of fancy hierarchy enabled that means I can't actually sort by any of those values.

I don't want the hierarchy, I just want to sort processes by, e.g. CPU usage. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an "All Processes" option in the hamburger menu on the right hand side. If I click this and disable "Dependencies" I get the expected behaviour.